# How to change row color when hovering

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Is there a props in [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) to change the row color while hovering?

Something like this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3u8si).

Thank you

Comment: you can add your own className attribute to mui table rows or cells and add your css then on hover. Also look for root class in mui styles and api documentation for further references. with root class you can customize any child element.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [styling section](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling) in the documentation, you can pass a `rowStyle` props, like this :

```
options={{
  rowStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#EEE',
  }
}}
```

You can also use the `onHover`'s React hook on your table component and apply your hover's  style there.